# Solving equations involving the modified Bessel function

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, special-functions, parametric-functions

I want to solve this equation

```
Solve[s^2/y^2 (x - y + 2 g BesselI[1, s/y]) == 2 g y BesselI[1, s/y], s]
```

and substitute `s` in

```
Sqrt[(Gamma^2 - 1)/(1 + (s/y)^2)] == x + 2 g (1 + (s/y)^2)/(s/y) BesselI[1, s/y]
```

so that `g = 0.05` and `Gamma = 2.957` and solve it.

How can I do this and how can plot `y` versus `x`?

Comment: Note that `Gamma` is a protected symbol denoting the gamma function.  You should use maybe `gamma`.  In general, if you avoid start your variables & functions with lowercase letters, you won't conflict with the built-in symbols.

Comment: A better way to describe the problem is that you have 3 variables and two equations, and you want to eliminate one of the variables, $s$.

Answer (score 5):

Although it is possible to eliminate `s` numerically (probably with `FindRoot`) to obtain `y` as a numerical function of `x`, which then can be plotted, it is much easier to obtain `x` and `y` as symbolic functions of a third variable, after which they can be plotted using `ParametricPlot`.  Begin by introducing a new variable, `z == s/y`, and inserting values for `g` and `gamma`.

```
eq = {(s^2/y^2 (x - y + 2 g BesselI[1, s/y]) == 2 g y BesselI[1, s/y]), 
    Sqrt[(gamma^2 - 1)/(1 + (s/y)^2)] == x + 2 g (1 + (s/y)^2)/(s/y) BesselI[1, s/y]}
    /. s -> z y /. {g -> 0.05, gamma -> 2.957}
(* {z^2 (x - y + 0.1 BesselI[1, z]) == 0.1 y BesselI[1, z], 
    2.78278 Sqrt[1/(1 + z^2)] == x + (0.1 (1 + z^2) BesselI[1, z])/z} *)
```

Next, solve for `x` and `y` in terms of `z`

```
sol = {x, y} /. Flatten@Solve[eq, {x, y}]
(* {2.78278 Sqrt[1/(1. + z^2)] - (0.1 BesselI[1., z])/z - 0.1 z BesselI[1., z], 
    -((0.1 (-27.8278 z^2 Sqrt[1/(1. + z^2)] + 1. z BesselI[1., z] - 
 1. z^2 BesselI[1., z] + 1. z^3 BesselI[1., z]))/(1. z^2 + 0.1 BesselI[1., z]))} *)
```

and plot.

```
ParametricPlot[sol, {z, 10^-10, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Bold]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very slick answer.

Answer (score 2):

Little addendum to the fine answer of @bbgodfrey

There is also a y-x-solution for negative z and therefore negative s

```
ParametricPlot[sol, {z, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Bold], 
    RegionFunction -> ((#3 < -.09) || (#3 > 10^-10) &)]
```

[image]